# DOS USB stick boots fine except on this Dell system

Tags: boot, usb

I'm in the process of trying to run the tool [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) from a USB stick.

I can successfully run it on one of my machines, but when trying to boot from the same USB stick on a Dell Optiplex 755 I just get the message:

```
Disk I/O error
Replace the disk, and then press any key
```

after POST. This is surprising to me since I can easily run a modern Linux distro from the very same USB drive on this Dell computer. It can obviously read the drive just fine, but as soon as I create a bootable MHDD drive it just refuses to boot it. I have tried it repeatedly.

Both machines are BIOS -- at least I assume the Dell one is since it's from 2008 and it's referring to "BIOS Version" in its own setup utility as well as on its support webpage.

The MHDD image is FAT12. Is booting a DOS USB drive in BIOS mode not file system agnostic, or what's the cause here?

Comment: Probably an oversight by the Dell bios engineers that may never get fixed. Have you looked through the bios settings for any setting that is unusual?

Comment: @Moab Yes, I've looked around but I couldn't see anything unusual. I also tried creating a FAT32 FreeDOS stick with Rufus, and just manually copy the tool to it which worked instantly. I wish I knew the details of why it behaves so differently.

Comment: May have something to do with this....https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block